# Getting rows affected in stored procedure INSERT statement with NOCOUNT OFF

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2014 where I first delete data from a table and execute another stored procedure as shown below.  I don't care about rows affected on this code so I use SET NOCOUNT ON.  I then perform an Insert statement first setting SET NOCOUNT OFF.  I would expect the stored procedure to return the rows affected automatically from the INSERT but that has not proven to be the case.  I searched SO and found the @@ROWCOUNT and that is working.  However, is that really required?  Why wouldn't the INSERT statement in the code below return the records affected?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveTextSetting]
    @UserId INT ,
    @SettingType INT = 0 ,
    @SettingValue NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
    BEGIN
        BEGIN
            SET NOCOUNT ON;
            DELETE  FROM Settings
            WHERE   UserId = @UserId
                    AND SettingType = @SettingType;
            EXEC dbo.PurgeExpiredSettings;
        END;
        BEGIN
            SET NOCOUNT OFF;
            INSERT  INTO dbo.Settings
                    ( UserId ,
                      SettingsText ,
                      SettingType
                    )
            VALUES  ( @UserId ,
                      @SettingValue ,
                      @SettingType
                    );
            RETURN @@ROWCOUNT; --without this we don't get the rows affected
        END;
    END;
```

Comment: Because the return value from a stored procedure is not intended to return a value. It returns a status code that indicates the status of the execution. If you want to return a value you should use an OUTPUT parameter instead.

Comment: "Why wouldn't the INSERT statement in the code below return the records affected?" 1) If you had two statements with nocount off, which value should SQL Server return? 2) It is returning it, just not via the return value. You can see this if you run the procedure in SSMS.

Comment: @SeanLange - Technically the return value of a stored proc is just an integer. The values of that integer and what they mean are up to the developer. So it could very easily be the number of rows affected.

Comment: The NOCOUNT setting does not affect `@@ROWCOUNT`, it determines whether SQL returns a message indicating the number of rows affect to the client (i.e. the '(X row(s) affected)` you see in the Messages tab of the Management Studio). Where are you not getting the rows affected? In the code that calls this stored proc?

Comment: @CodeNaked yes the RETURN_VALUE is an integer but in practice and by MS documentation it is intended to return a status code indicating execution status. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx This of course could be used to return the number of rows affected but is non-standard.

Comment: @CodeNaked As you can see from my sample the top two calls are NOCOUNT ON as I don't want that interfering with the rows affected result (i.e. the Delete statement). Then I SET NOCOUNTOFF so that the INSERT would return the rows affected but that has not been working so I had to add the @@ROWCOUNT return which solves it.  It's just not as expected as I would expect with NOCOUNT OFF and the final INSERT it would return 1 for the 1 affected insert.

Comment: @SeanLange - Yeah, I agree. Not the best practice. @Nel - Like I said `SET NOCOUNT` has no affect on `@@ROWCOUNT`, so it doesn't matter if you have it set to `ON` or `OFF`. I suspect when you say "without this we don't get the rows affected", you mean you don't get the rows affected in the caller to the stored proc (i.e. `EXEC @result = [dbo].[SaveTextSetting](...); PRINT @result;` works, but `EXEC [dbo].[SaveTextSetting](...); PRINT @@ROWCOUNT;` does not. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spTest AS RETURN
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE spTest
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
    DECLARE @rt int
    CREATE TABLE #t (
        v int NOT NULL
    )
    INSERT INTO #t (v)
    SELECT v FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (2)) AS t (v) 
    SET @rt = @@ROWCOUNT
    DROP TABLE #t
    RETURN @rt
END
GO

DECLARE @rt int
EXEC @rt = spTest
SELECT @rt
GO

DROP PROCEDURE spTest
GO
```

Comment: Your example above is a bit different.  Try performing a code block first with SET NOCOUNT ON and then after that completes do another operation with SET NOCOUNT OFF and see what happens.  See how my example first does a DELETE then executes a stored procedure prior to the INSERT which I'm expecting a rows affected result from?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you use?

Comment: Using SET ROWCOUNT will not affect DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE statements in a future release of SQL Server. Avoid using SET ROWCOUNT with DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE statements in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. For a similar behavior, use the TOP syntax. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

Comment: The @@ROWCOUNT function is updated even when SET NOCOUNT is ON. The setting specified by SET NOCOUNT is in effect at execute or run time and not at parse time. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would use an output param something like.....

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveTextSetting]
    @UserId       INT ,
    @SettingType  INT = 0 ,
    @SettingValue NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @RowCount     INT             OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DELETE  FROM Settings
   WHERE   UserId = @UserId
     AND   SettingType = @SettingType;

  EXEC dbo.PurgeExpiredSettings;

  INSERT  INTO dbo.Settings( UserId ,SettingsText ,SettingType)
  VALUES  ( @UserId ,@SettingValue ,@SettingType);

      SET @RowCount=  @@ROWCOUNT; 
END
```